# How can I float right two span tags on different lines?

Tags: css, css-float, block, html

I have three span tags: One is floated left (A) and the other two are floated right (B and C).

[image: Span Tags]

However, what I want is to have C positioned below B but both be floated right; that is, on different lines.  I tried to use display:block on B, but that didn't seem to help.  How can this be done using span tags (not div)?

Here is my css:

```
#A {
  float:left;
}

#B {
  float:right;
}

#C {
  float:right;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is add `clear: right` to `#C`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/w7K4t/

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="A">A</span>
    <span id="B">B</span>
    <span id="C">C</span>
</div>


#A {
    float: left;
}
#B {
    float: right;
}
#C {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  For some reason, I had thought you could only use clear or float for one element, as I just tried clear:right, which wasn't working.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try putting a width and height on #A.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line break (`<br/>`) after the `span` containing B.

```
<span style="float:left">A</span>

<span style="float:right">B</span><br/>

<span style="float:right">C</span>
```